# Replace part of link href in ASP.NET WEB FORMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, webforms, header

I would like to replace `http://www.somewebsite.com` programmaticaly when page loads.

Is it possible to do?

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://www.somewebsite.com/App_Themes/Blue/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="www.somewebsite.com/inc/styles_ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <link href="http://www.somewebsite.com/App_Themes/RedBlack/StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found a really good example how to do it http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/523983/Adding-Styles-Dynamically-to-ASP-NET-Page-Header

```
Literal cssFile = new Literal()
{
    Text = @"<link href=""" + Page.ResolveUrl(styleFilePath) + 
    @""" type=""text/css"" rel=""stylesheet""/>"
};
Page.Header.Controls.Add(cssFile);
```